# Consultas en PHP

Tags: php

Alguien me puede decir como simplificar estas consultas, tengo una tabla llamada tabla1 y en ella tengo dos campos, clave e inscrito.

```
clave
100
101
102
...
150
```

a través de una consulta me muestra cuantos están inscritos al curso con clave 100 y así para cada clave, pero como hacer esto mismo sin tener que escribir 50 veces todo el código de abajo. Podrían poner un ejemplo de como hacer estas consultas, agradezco su amable ayuda.

```
$consulta = mysqli_query($conexion, "SELECT * from tabla1 WHERE clave=100") 
or die ("Error al traer datos");

$total = mysqli_num_rows($consulta);
printf("El resultado tiene %d filas.\n", $total);
```

Comment: No sabes hacer una iteracion, o entiendo mal la pregunta?

Comment: Espera.. vos queres saber el total de incriptos por clave?

Comment: Entiende bien la pregunta, la verdad no se como se hace, ojala alguien pueda decirme como.

Comment: Usa un foreach, [aquí la documentación](https://www.php.net/manual/es/control-structures.foreach.php).

Comment: Asi es gbianchi quiero saber el total por clave

Comment: gracias Jonathan Arias leere foreach

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hola @mass según lo que entiendo de tu pregunta lo que necesitas es la cantidad de usuarios inscritos por clave?

Si es eso, puedes hacer una query que te entregue esa información. Tendrías que usar el modificador `COUNT` y `GROUP BY` de SQL.

Quedaría algo así

```
SELECT clave, COUNT(clave) as inscritos FROM tabla1 GROUP BY clave;
```

Luego podrías usar la respuesta de @jolsalazar para recorrer esta nueva tabla.

Editó su respuesta antes de terminar :( jaja

Saludos!

Comment: Que amable crepu considerare tu aporte y tambien el de @jolsalazar la verdad no se como se hace esto

Comment: por que sale este error: Warning: mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in

Answer (score 2):

Tendrias que modificar tu consulta de SQL, sacando la cantidad de cada clave.

```
SELECT clave, count(*) as inscritos from tabla1 group by clave;
```

Luego el resultado tendrías que recorrerlo con un `foreach` donde muestras el código y la cantidad de inscritos

La iteración tendria que ser de esta forma

```
while ($fila = mysql_fetch_array($consulta, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
    printf("Clave: %s  Inscritos: %s", $fila["clave"], $fila["inscritos"]);  
}
```

Ahora bien te comparto ese ejemplo utilizando `mysql_fetch_array`, funcion que en PHP 7 ya esta deprecada. Uso esa función por tu codigo de ejemplo y entendiendo de que no usas PHP 7

[Documentacion](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-array.php)

Comment: Igual OP dice que no sabe como hacer una iteracion. Ademas de que esta es la solucion (podrias explicar un poco mas el query), estaria bueno agregar como hacer el for del resultado...

Comment: graciaspor tu amable ayuda jolsalazar, ¿pero como hago la comparaciono el rrecorrdio por clave despues de la consulta?

Comment: Acabo de actualizar mi respuesta, espero te ayude.

Comment: tienes razon jolsalazar no uso php7 jejeje la verdad apenas estoy aprendiendo y te reitero mi agradecimiento por tu ayuda, soy nuevo en este foro no se si se pueden dar puntos me gustaria darles por su ayuda

Comment: una pregunta jolsalazar en esta parte  $fila["clave"] pongo el 100 para que solo me muestre los de esa clave?

Comment: probaste el codigo, ese bucle te mostrará todos los codigos y la cantidad de inscritos.

Comment: me muestra esto:  Warning: mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in